# Sub-component routing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I recently start work with react and have a doubt

What is the best way to do sub component routing? I know this kind of sub component routing like  `'/login/component1'`, `'/login/component2....'`  but what I want is that it will work in this manner that `'/login'` is not appended with `/component1` In short way, path needs to be fixed with inner view  routing (I am using react-router v4 for routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can add children to your paths:

```
 let routes={
    path: '', component: BasicLayoutComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'treatments',             
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: TreatmentListComponent
                },
                {
                    path: 'new',
                    component: NewTreatmentComponent,
                    canActivate: [HasClinics]

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

So you have `/treatments/` and `/treatments/new` as valid paths

Comment: Thanks for reply but I want my url fixed in sub component routing  which show only /treatments on browser  for  list component not  /treatments/list